# "libertineotf.sty" not found

Tags: latex, miktex

I am using MikTeX 2.9.7364 with WinEdit in windows10, and encounter an error saying`"libertineotf.sty" not found.` I search it in google find that it`s a package used in Linux, but why it occurs here? And I search "libertineotf.sty" in MikTex Console and find nothing. Who can help me?

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

libertineotf.sty is obsolete (see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertineotf)

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding "use `libertine` instead."